# Generating function problem for two tasks

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> Question: A semester of a college has $n$ days, how many ways can we separate the semester into sessions if each session has to consists of at least 5 days?

I think I'm simply stuck at the first step of this question. I'm not sure how to start a good approach to it.

However, this seems solvable by using generating function. The first task is separating the semester into each session. The second task is doing something to each session which is each session has to consists of at least 5 days. I'm stuck on writing the calculation explicitly at this moment,  any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: For the generating function approach: Ignore $n$ for now.  Break into cases based on how many distinct sessions there are.  If there was only one session, that has gf $(x^5+x^6+x^7+\dots)$  If there were two sessions, pick the length of the first session then the length of the second session, so $(x^5+x^6+x^7+\dots)^2$.  Continue in this manner.  This gives the total as the coefficient of $x^n$ of the expansion of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty (\sum\limits_{j=5}^\infty x^j)^i$.  You can simplify this further using geometric series

Comment: Thanks for helping. So if I use geometric series, we know that $$\sum_{n = N}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x^N}{1-x}$$ Thus $$\sum_{i  =1}^{\infty}(\sum_{j = 5}^{\infty} x^j)^i = \sum_{i  =1}^{\infty}(\frac{x^5}{1-x})^i = \frac{\frac{x^5}{1-x}}{1 - \frac{x^5}{1-x}}$$
But is there any way I can still simplify from here? Or what should I do to go further?